# EmguCV C# 3.1 - DrawPolyline(PointF[], Boolean, TColor, Int32) syntax error

Tags: c#, emgucv

Probably it is something easy but I cannot find the method. I am trying this code to draw an ARC segment with float points:

System.Drawing.PointF[] points = new PointF[20];

background.DrawPolyline(points, false, new Bgr(0, 0, 0), 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.FourConnected, 0);

According to the documentation in
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/53068d61-8b55-789f-5d3c-6ed2288f073e.htm

the DrawPolyline method can use PointF[] as input. However, I get error when I type it. I am using EmguCV 3.1. Also, I tried "Go to definition" and I cannot find this method in the .cs file. Someone knows why? I changed from 2.4 to 3.1 just because I though I can find this method in the new version, but I still cannot find it.

I hope someone can help me. If someone knows a better way to draw an arc, also welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what background is but if it is an Image you can find the documentation here: [Image.DrawPolyline](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/c2f4e73b-6344-7b3b-6a98-0efb8222129f.htm) or if it is a Map then here: [Map.DrawPolyline](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/53068d61-8b55-789f-5d3c-6ed2288f073e.htm)

In the documentation you will see that you cannot use PointF but must use System.Drawing.Point. Here is an example from an application I have been working on:

```
foreach (RControl r in _instruments.Values)
{
    PointF[] points = r.BackgroundRotatedRect.GetVertices();
    Bgra rectangleStroke = new Bgra(
        ((SolidColorBrush)r.RectangleStroke).Color.B,
        ((SolidColorBrush)r.RectangleStroke).Color.G,
        ((SolidColorBrush)r.RectangleStroke).Color.R,
        ((SolidColorBrush)r.RectangleStroke).Color.A);

    _recorderFrame.FrameImage.DrawPolyline(
                                Array.ConvertAll(points, new Converter<PointF, System.Drawing.Point>(PointFConverter.PointFToPoint)),
                                true,
                                rectangleStroke,
                                2,
                                Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.FourConnected);
}
```

Hope this helps,
Doug

Comment: background is Image<TColor, TDepth>. It means I should convert the image into map to use the drawPolyline with PointF?

Comment: @Pablo, no no need to convert to a Map. Use the Image<>.DrawPolyline method and convert your points from PointF to Point and you should be all set to go.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, I am trying to draw a precise arc shape. I need the decimal part of the number too.

Comment: Yes, you can use a PointF for drawing an arc if using a Map object. Misunderstood.